# How to add ID column to email alert

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, microsoft-flow

A unique incremental ID is created and added to the SharePoint list, when a new Form is submitted. Now I want to create a workflow that triggers an email when new item is submitted. I have used send customized email template to trigger an email but i want to add ID column also to that email.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a variable, then set the default value to the ID field?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use Flow to send the alert email, the item ID is a dynamic value free to be insert in the subject or email body.

You can trigger the flow on item creation and then find the ID under “**When an item is created**”.

Please see a sample flow here:

[image]